# Categorize values in Select query

Tags: vb.net, linq

I want to categorize values in a select linq query. The following works but is very messy if you have a lot of categories:

```
 Dim query = From element In Ticket.GetTickets
 Select New With {
 .Code = If(element.Val <= 1, 1, If(element.Val <= 1.25 And element.Val > 1, 2, 0))}
```

So I thought I write an extention method for that purpose

```
Module Categorization
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub Categorize(ByVal aValue As Double)
        If aValue <= 1 Then
            aValue = 1
        ElseIf aValue > 1 And aValue <= 1.25 Then
            aValue = 2
        Else
            aValue = 0
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

But if I try to apply the method

```
Dim query = From element In Ticket.GetTickets
                    Select New With {
                        .Code = If(element.Val <= 1, 1, If(element.Val <= 1.25 And element.Val > 1, 2, 0)),
                        .Test = element.Val.Categorize
                    }
```

I always get the compile error: `Expression has no value` (message might be a bit different, I translated it). Anyone who can help me get this extention method working. I am open for any better Ideas solving the categorization problem as well.

To run this I want to deliver the Class I used as an example:

```
Public Class Ticket
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property Val As Double

    Public Shared Function GetTickets() As list(Of Ticket)
        Return New List(Of Ticket) From {New Ticket With {.id = 1, .Val = 0.9867},
        New Ticket With {.id = 2, .Val = 1.23},
        New Ticket With {.id = 3, .Val = 1.5}}
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

The extention method that works for me is:

```
Public Module Categorization
    <Extension()>
    Public Function Categorize(ByVal val As Double) As UInt16
        Dim reVal As UInt16
        If val <= 1 Then
            reVal = 1
        ElseIf (1 <= val) AndAlso (val < 1.25) Then
            reVal = 2
        Else
            reVal = 0
        End If

        Return reVal

    End Function
End Module
```

Now I can fire the query:

```
Dim query = From element In Ticket.GetTickets
                    Select New With {
                        .Code = If(element.Val <= 1, 1, If(element.Val <= 1.25 And element.Val > 1, 2, 0)),
                        .Test = element.Val.Categorize
                    }
```